# Would a Dwarf Stonecaller get two saves against prone?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Dwarf Racial power **Stand Your Ground** states:

> When an attack would knock you prone, you can make a saving throw to avoid falling prone.

The Invoker Stonecaller Paragon Path feature **Strong Footing** states:

> When any attack would knock you prone, you can make a saving throw. If you save, you don’t fall prone.

Would a Dwarf Stonecaller make two saves when an attack would knock them prone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Put simply. If a rule allows you to make an additional save, then you get an additional save. There is no rule that states that you can't ever save more than once against a given effect.